# Accessing python parent folder

Tags: python, import, directory, parent

I've looked through previous answers which seem to suggest I should be able to use:

```
from .. import code
```

though it produces this:
    ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

though this doesn't seem to be working. My file structure is as follows:

```
scraper/
    __init__.py
    bot/
            scraper.py
            __init__.py
            wigan/ 
                    council.py
                    __init__.py
```

I'm able to from scraper load council using:

```
from wigan import council
```

though from council, none of the following work when trying to load scraper.py:

```
from .. import scraper
from scraper.bot import scraper
from scraper.bot.scraper import scraper
```

Any help would be great. Thanks :-)

Comment: What kind of error you get? Exception, warning, or just nothing?

Comment: ImportError when I try do scraper.bot, ValueError when I use ..

Comment: you should put the scraper folder into 'site-packages' or into another folder in `import sys; print(sys.path)` and retry the import statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem you're having is that you're running a script that is located in package. This is one of the most awkwardly supported features in Python. When you run a script directly, it puts your current path at the start of the Python search path. If you're inside of a package though, this will be wrong.

To properly run `scrapper.py` (if that's your script), you should change to the top level folder (whatever is above `scrapper/`), then run `python -m scrapper.bot.scrapper`.

Or, if you add that top level folder to the Python search path, either by using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or by installing it (or an appropriate `.pth` file) into the `site-packages` folder, then the current directory restriction will be relaxed and you can run the script from anywhere.

There are other issues with running modules as scripts if you're also going to import them by name from other modules. The script will be imported as `__main__`, not as its actual name. If you import it by name too, you'll get a second copy of the script, which may mean it doesn't work as intended (if there is any global state in the module, it may be inconsistent between the copies). This is one reason it is often suggested that scripts do as little work as possible (just import something from another module, and then run it). You may want to refactor your code to do this too.